# bucket data into ntiles mysql

Tags: mysql, join, rank, bucket

I am trying to do a standard bucketing of data in mysql: split the data along some characteristic into N buckets and assign the bucket number to each entry.  The entries consist of date, permno and volume as follows:

> dte, permno, volume, day_rank
>
> 1986-03-07, 10071,   9203,   NULL

The table is titled bam. On each date (dte) there are many permnos (ids) that I would like to rank on the basis of volume.  I would then like to assign the ranking for each permno, dte to day_rank.  A successful query would thus rank the permnos for each dte based on volume.  I am attempting to do this with this convoluted query:

```
 select a.dte, a.permno, count(b.volume) as rnk
 from bam a inner join bam b
 on a.dte = b.dte and (a.volume < b.volume or (a.permno=b.permno and a.volume =      b.volume))
 order by a.dte, a.volume;
```

This works however it is very very slow to the point where for a table that's reasonably sized it would take ~1 day to run.

Any ideas?